# Zsh on CentOS8 places functions from /usr/share/Modules before my user defined ones

Tags: centos, zsh

Any advice on the following issue would be greatly appreciated.

I am running zsh on CentOS8. I am facing the following issue: The shell seems to be unwilling to put my user defined functions first.

`echo $fpath` gives me `/usr/share/Modules/init/zsh-functions` first, and only then `/home/user/bin/fns /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/share/zsh/5.5.1/functions`

My .zshenv file reads as follows:

```
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
export VISUAL=/usr/bin/vim

typeset -U path
path=(~/bin ~/progs/bin $path)
[[ $fpath = *user* ]] || fpath=(~user/bin/fns $fpath)
autoload ${fpath[1]}/*(:t)
```

[Note: actual `user-name` changed to the generic `user`.]

This is the same .zshenv file I use, without any issues, on my OSX and Debian based systems. I feel that I am missing something obvious, yet I can not, for the life of me, understand what it is and why the behavior is different on CentOS.  Multiple Google searches have turned out to be less than helpful, and I now find myself screaming curses at the screen...

Thank you for taking the time to read this and thank you, in advance, for any helpful advice.

Comment: After some experimenting, and a lot of cursing, in English as well as Romanian, implemented the following workaround:  I have commented out the last two lines of the the **.zshenv** file and placed them, along with a `typeset -U path` (so as to avoid duplicates) in my **.zshrc** file.

Comment: `/usr/share/Modules/init/zsh-functions` is not there at all as standard. You should check what is adding it and what files it contains. It must be added to `$fpath` somewhere in either one of your dot-files or the system ones.